# Excel Adjacent Cell Value Based On Largest Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet called Settings with cells such as:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Payment | as of |
| 2 | 25.00 | January 2022 |
| 3 | 27.00 | April 2022 |
| 4 | 29.00 | July 2022 |

And a sheet called "Person"

| A (date) | B (Payment amount) |
| --- | --- |
| January 2022 | *25.00* |
| February 2022 | *25.00* |
| March 2022 | *25.00* |
| April 2022 | *27.00* |
| May 2022 | *27.00* |
| June 2022 | *27.00* |
| July 2022 | *29.00* |
| August 2022 | *29.00* |

What I'd like to accomplish is that the Payment column is populated by the Payment in Settings column A corresponding to the *most recent previous or current date* in Settings Column B (relative to Person Column A).

The desired output would be the italic values in the Payment column above.

I think I can use aggregate (14,6) for this but I just can't figure out how.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If those dates are true dates then Index/match or xlookup will do it.

Comment: Thank you!  Index and Match worked for me.